# .htaccess Rewrite Rule Possibility?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm having a little issue.  One of my clients recently sent out an email blast to 6500 people, that included an invalid link to a PDF file.

The link was simply: http://theirsite.com/pdf/thepdf.pdf%20

So, I'd like to be able to do an htaccess rewrite for them to the valid http://theirsite.com/pdf/thepdf.pdf file

So far, everything I've tried does not work.

Here is what I've tried thus far:

```
RewriteRule ^(/pdf/thepdf.pdf[%20|\s]+)$ /pdf/thepdf.pdf [R=301,L]

RewriteRule /pdf/thepdf.pdf([%20|\s]+)$ /pdf/thepdf.pdf [R=301,L]

RewriteRule /pdf/thepdf.pdf%20 /pdf/thepdf.pdf [R=301,L]

RewriteRule /pdf/thepdf.pdf%20 /pdf/thepdf.pdf [R=301,L]
RewriteRule /pdf/thepdf.pdf  /pdf/thepdf.pdf [R=301,L]

RewriteRule /pdf/thepdf.pdf(.+?) /pdf/thepdf.pdf [R=301,L]
```

Something to note here, if I click the original link, but remove the %20 and put in a space, the rewrite works.

Just does not work with the %20

Comment: Apache should take care of cleaning white spaces at the end of an url. What king of error are you getting ? A 404 ?

Comment: yes, a 404 error.   Apache is not taking care of it, and no, I do not have control over the server, nor apache.  LOL  I was luck enough to get them to allow an .htaccess file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is .htaccess there should not be a mandatory forward slash at the beginning of the match rule.  Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?pdf/thepdf\.pdf\s+$ /pdf/thepdf.pdf [R=301,L]
```

Note:

- I put a `/?` at the beginning of the match rule as this is good general practice to make the rule work in either a host config context or an .htaccess context. Since a `/` would be required if this rule was in host config.
- You should escape the `.` before `.pdf` otherwise it will act as a wildcard match.
- I added anchors (`^` and `$`) at the beginning and the end of the match to make sure this matches the entire resource string

Answer (score 0):

`%20` is a URL encoded space, so you can use a lazy select `(.+?)` in your `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule /pdf/thepdf.pdf(.+?) /pdf/thepdf.pdf [L]
```

These rules should normally work.

Comment: i would think so as well, but it did not work.   Same 404 error

Comment: yes, I have verified that the rewrite mod is enabled, as it is working for some other links (proper links)